# What differences are there between the various version of emacs available?

Tags: 10.10, emacs

Ubuntu (10.10) offers emacs21,22,23 and emacs-snapshot. What are the differences between them and which one does the `emacs` package install by default? Also, I presume `emacs-snapshot-gtk` is the most up to date one. I would like to use this because it seems to pay attention to my `.Xdefaults` settings, which `emacs` doesn't. What disadvantages might this cause?

I use emacs for LaTeX, ORGmode and ESS/R programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`emacs-snapshot` is a development version of Emacs. It has more goodies but likely also more bugs, so use it at your own risk. The others are released versions; the only reason I can think not to install the latest one is if you're very short on disk space.

The [`emacs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/emacs) package depends on `emacs23` (you can see the dependencies in any package administration tool).

Gtk programs don't use X resources (`.Xdefaults`). Non-gtk (but X) versions of Emacs do.

Comment: emacs22 will be going away in favor of emacs23, so you can safely ignore emacs22.

Comment: So if I want to make use of `.Xdefaults` what do I use? (I thought this was a difference between `emacs` and `emacs-snapshot` but apparently not...)

Comment: Move the contents of `.Xdefaults` into `.Xresources` seems to have made the standard `emacs` recognise it.

Comment: @Seamus: Short answer: `~/.Xresources` is the file to use. Long answer: X resources are stored on the server. On Ubuntu and most other unix systems, when you log in, `~/.Xresources` is loaded. A few other systems load `~/.Xdefaults`, but not Ubuntu. A few applications look for their own resources in `~/.Xdefaults` when they start, but not Emacs (at least not `emacs23-x` on 10.04, though it loads `~/.Xdefaults-$(hostname)`). If you change your resource file, you can load it manually with `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` (`-load` would also override any system resources).